# Added sugar RDI for a performing athlete

Tags: sugar

What is the recommended DI of glucose/added sugars for a performing athlete, say, participating in a high intensity sport?

According the American Heart Association an average male is recommended 37.5 grams/day while an average female is recommended 25 grams/day. How much do these values vary in comparison to a performing athlete?

Comment: Please avoid cross posting the same question to different sites.

Comment: Please define RDI.

Comment: @CareyGregory RDI = Recommended Daily Intake, I think?

Comment: @NateBarbettini I figured probably but this is an international forum and English isn't everyone's first language. Abbreviations should be spelled out the first time they're used.